# react native Xcodeのエラー

Tags: ios, xcode, node.js, reactjs

react-nativeをXcodeで実行しようとしてエラーが出ます。

```
DEST=/Users/(Username)/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sample-djxgbolzezazefbovcdjimcomloy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sample.app
+ react-native bundle --entry-file index.ios.js --platform ios --dev true --bundle-output /Users/(Username)/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sample-djxgbolzezazefbovcdjimcomloy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sample.app/main.jsbundle --assets-dest /Users/gitan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sample-djxgbolzezazefbovcdjimcomloy/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sample.app
../node_modules/react-native/packager/react-native-xcode.sh: line 36: react-native: command not found
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 127
```

Xcode,node.jsのアップデートに伴い、エラーが発生するようになりました。
node_modulesのpathが通ってないのでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

同じ現象に悩まされており、
react-native-xcode.sh で
export PATH=$HOME/.nodebrew/current/bin:$PATH
のようにパスを通せばとりあえず動くようになりました

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3948